# Javascript "If" statement or "&&" logical operator

Tags: javascript, operators

Should one "if" statements be preferred over logical operators or vice-versa? 
Examples:

```
if(foo) {
  bar();
}
// compared to:
foo && bar();
```

```
if(foo){
  bar();
}else{
  baz();
}
// compared to:
foo? bar() : baz();
```

Considerations & questions:

1. Is there a best practice?
2. Should readability or code length be considered?
3. Are there performance differences?
4. "If" statements allow for early exit through "return" & "break". Can this be achieved through operators?

Comment: Preference => Opinion-Based Question.

Comment: IMO `&&` and the conditional operator should only be used when you need to *use the resulting expression* - otherwise, you've used an operator that results in an expression, but the expression goes unused. Sure, you can use them for code golfing, but I find `if` / `else` more readable. `"If" statements allow for early exit through "return" & "break"` <- is not correct.

Comment: `foo && bar();` if you only need to execute the function when condition is `true`; otherwise `if` can give you more flexibility

Comment: Actually there is a practice (not sure if it's the best). Expressions are returning a value, which should be used. I.e. don't put an expression alone on the line just because of the side effects. The intention of the code should be clear. You're not supposed to minify code during developement, the minifying is done when the code is taken to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is there a best practice?

   I would suggest `if statement` for maximum code readability. && can use when you are resulting a expression
2. Should readability or code length be considered?

   Same above, these code can be minified by plugins like `babel-minify`.
3. Are there performance differences?

   I don't know, but less code will be better if you are targeting web, and I would say guessing browser engine performance is not a good idea since they are changing all day.
4. "If" statements allow for early exit through "return" & "break".

   yes